# Is the delta neighborhood of an epsilon neighborhood of a complete metric space the same as the delta + epsilon neighborhood

Tags: metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples, complete-spaces

Let `X` be a complete  metric space. Does there exist a compact subset `A` that is non empty s.t. the delta neighborhood of the epsilon neighborhood of A is not the same as the epsilon + delta neighborhood?

I start by taking the closed unit interval. I'm thinking of looking at two points that do not coincide. Then take epsilon so the neighborhoods around the points don't touch, but I don't think that works.

(I've been advised to use a finite subset of a Euclidean space as `X`.)

Comment: What do you mean by "finite" in "complete finite metric space"? If you mean the underlying set is finite, then the space is automatically complete, every subset is compact, and the example does not fit the question as the underlying set is infinite.

Comment: Sorry. I meant finite subset of a Euclidean space.

Comment: That I don't understand either, for the same reason. Maybe you mean "bounded"?

Comment: Sorry, I'm just using a little remark from my lecture notes. I suppose that is wrong. I think indeed he meant bounded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as $|X| > 1$ yes. Let $x \in X$. Since $X$ is finite $$d := \inf_{y \in X\setminus \{x\}} d(x,y) > 0$$ Then $$N_{\frac{3d}{4}}(N_{\frac{3d}{4}}(x)) = N_{\frac{3d}{4}}(x)= \{x\}$$ On the other hand, there is $y \in X$ with $y \neq x$ so that $d(y, x) = d$ so $y \in N_{\frac{3d}{4} + \frac{3d}{4}}(x)$.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!

Comment: This answer assumes finiteness of the set which is a dubious condition as per comments. However, it does work as a counterexample to every way I can think of making sense of the question. +1

Answer (score 1):

I can give you an example in a noneuclidean space.

Take X to be any discrete metric space containing more than one points . It is complete.

Consider any $\{x\}$ it is compact. And if you take $\epsilon =3/4, \delta =1/2$ you get the example.

Now a non-singleton finite subset of an euclidean space is discrete. Only you have to choose $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ carefully.